# INSERT into table without specifying Column names

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have `INVOICE` `TABLE`
I want to insert value by not specifying column names
using `SQL Server`, I have tried this but it is not working..please help

```
INSERT INTO INVOICE
VALUES( 1,1,KEYBOARD,1,15,5,75)
```

Comment: without your table structure, we won't be able to help...

Comment: and the error is? What is `KEYBOARD`? Have you specified all the columns? Its well documented http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx

Comment: INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...)
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);

Comment: @Tarek This is what the OP is trying to avoid.

Comment: @Curt sorry man, I got u, but I had this before and it was because of default value for date, so you may pay attention for that.

Answer (score 54):

As long as you have the right number of columns in your INSERT statement, and as long as all the values except KEYBOARD are some numeric data type, and as long as you have suitable permissions, this should work.

```
INSERT INTO INVOICE VALUES( 1,1,'KEYBOARD',1,15,5,75);
```

SQL requires single quotes around text values.

But not using column names isn't a good practice. It's not unheard of for people to change the order of columns in a table. Changing the order of columns isn't a good practice, either, but some people insist on doing it anyway.

If somebody does that, and swaps the 5th and 7th columns in your table, your INSERT statement will still succeed--both those columns are numeric--but the INSERT will screw up your data.

Comment: Just experienced this case when code in Production broke-up because my Team Lead just created the table on Prod DB with different order as they were on Staging DB. So, bad practise on both sides.

Comment: I just want to add that not using column names is called `"blind insert"` ant it's common SQL antipattern. The worst scenario is when INSERT works but data goes to wrong column (implicit casts and so on).

Comment: I have just added a new nullable column to a table where we have some of that Blind Inserting going on and the production started erroring, because the number of fields was mismatching with the number of values in the Blind Insert. I did not know we had Blind Inserts. My advise, don't be lazy! Do a proper insert and save yourself some headache.

Comment: Changing the order or columns may be a bad practice, but it may be a simple mistake. It may happen when you add columns with alter table and you forgot to add column A before adding column B. On the other hand, INSERT without field names is 99.99% of times a bad practice. It will stop working with column swaps, but also if I add an extra column to the table. It also worsens readability if table is large, and forces you to insert null in all non initialized columns.

Comment: @Rober2D2: One of the reasons I heard from people who purposely didn't include column names on INSERT is that they actually want it to break when extra columns have been added to the table. If you specify columns when doing INSERTs, and you add extra columns later on, the INSERTs would still work hence you won't notice those INSERTS would need to be changed for the extra columns.

Comment: @David Liang: I suppose using this kind of check may be a valid reason, but it will fail if new columns are nullable or have a default value (In any case, I can't see any scenario where I would use such a check). But I still think that ommiting column names would only lead to painful and difficult to track bugs. It wouldn't be the first time a column order is different in DEV, PRE and PRO environments. I really prefer not to depend on that

Answer (score 17):

Why would you want to do this?  Not specifying column names is bad coding practice.

In your case, though, `keyboard` needs to be surrounded by single quotes:

```
INSERT INTO INVOICE VALUES( 1,1, 'KEYBOARD',1,15,5,75)
```

If you just don't want to type the column names, you can get them easily in SQL Server Management Studio.  Open the "Object Browser", open the database, and choose "Tables".  Choose the `Invoice` table.  One of the options is "Columns".

Just click on the "Columns" name (no need to open it) and drag it into a query window.  It will insert the list of columns.

Comment: nice tip to drag and drop the columns in SQL studio. Saved me pain staking 40 mins of work.

Answer (score 9):

yes you can directly insert values into table as follows:

```
insert into `schema`.`tablename` values(val1,val2,val3);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
INSERT INTO INVOICE VALUES( 1,1,'KEYBOARD',1,15,5,75);
```

you forget to include the single quotes in keyboard,text required single quotes in sql