# Insert into database without specifying field names

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I'm using the following code to insert a single register of address in the database:

```
$this->db->insert('address', $address);
```

The command above inserts with:
Inesert into table(columns) values(values)
I would like to know, is there command to insert without having to specify the field names, using CodeIgniter framework and if possible, without having to handwrite the insert sql query? 
Like:
Insert into table values(values)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17189621/insert-into-table-without-specifying-column-names

Comment: @XaxD, I know it can be done, I just want to know how to do specifically with CodeIgniter, if possible, without having to handwrite the sql code, but using CodeIgniter framework.

Comment: have you tried `$this->db->insert(null, $address)` ?

Comment: @XaxD, null would be the value for the table, I must specify the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it can be done with raw `sql` But not on CI's  `db->insert` function, 
Why? because the **function/method** needs 2 parameters first is the table name and second an array of `key and values` where the keys is the DB table's column name and value is the column value.

Unless you create one or modify the existing function, but until that **NO** it cannot be done.

Try a different approach like using `$this->db->query('..query ..');` where you put your own `SQL`

Answer (score 1):

Late for party, i have tricky that with this code. With some note, just be sure `<input name="...">` have same name, with field name inside your table.

```
<input type="text" name="field_1">
```

Maybe can help somebody,

Example **Controller** :

```
function post() {
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $this->model_name->post_data();
    redirect('to_page_view');
  }
}
```

Example **Model** :

```
function post_data() {
  unset($_POST['submit']);
  $this->db->insert('table_name', $this->input->post());
}
```