# Insert the model field in the middle of existing one in Django

Tags: django, django-models

Say I'm trying to insert a new char field called tag, and I want it to be at the middle of existing table.

In django when I add the field and make the migration, it always add the new field to the end of the sql table.

I can't edit anything in the migration file either since it just adding one field:

```
operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='chat',
            name='tags',
            field=models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100, null=True),
        )
```

Is there anyway I can customize the order in django? Or I have to go to sql to do it manually.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no way for you to insert column between other columns without creating new tables. But I couldn't figure out the reason to have columns(model fields) in particular order, it doesn't make sense. In fact, I really doubt that there's any sql statement could directly reorder the column sequence for database schema.

Comment: Since I'm dealing with a table with a lot of columns, i have a function to upload values with query like: insert into values (%s, %s, ........ %s). I count the number of col to figure out how many %s I need to insert into the query. The last col is the foreign key I generated. The rest is the data I receive from somewhere else. Now the source of the data has one extra column in the middle, it will be really easy if I can just insert a column in the middle of my database

Comment: But isn't true that `insert into` still has to specify the column names like `insert into (col1, col2...) values (v1, v2)`? Do you manage the sql statement? What are you receiving exactly? sql statements or data? I was confused.

Comment: Not really. You can insert values without specifying col names.  INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (1,2,3,4,5);  So this way the order really matters.

Comment: OK sounds like you can, I never did that. But that's sounds really bad practice and discouraged by most people because it would have problem in exactly the situation you described: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17189621/insert-into-table-without-specifying-column-names. I would rather spend time fixing my sql statement than figuring out reordering columns.

Comment: So I just manually change the order and it works just fine. And you are right  this practice is not encouraged in some case. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

As you rightly guessed this is going to need a bit of custom sql which can be executed with [RunSQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/migration-operations/#runsql). That means you need to edit the generated migration file as follows:

```
operations = [
    migrations.RunSQL(
      "ALTER TABLE musician ADD COLUMN name varchar(255) NOT NULL;",
      state_operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
           model_name='chat',
           name='tags',
           field=models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100, null=True),
        )
     ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Shang Wang: "I really doubt that there's any sql statement could directly reorder the column sequence for database schema."
You are completely wrong!

```
ALTER TABLE CoreDB.country CHANGE column_to_move AFTER column_name_to_move_after;
```

Comment: HI, Ted. I think it should be a comment this way. However it can be a base of a solution. Maybe with the combination of e4c5's answer. Is this solution specific to a given database? E.g. are there some restriction, something like it works in PostgreSQL, but not in MySQL and SQLite.