# Insert random row(s) in SQL Server without addressing each column by name?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that I want to populate with 10M random rows. There are recipes for doing so, but the complexity I have is that there are also lots of columns, so explicitly writing an expression for random data for each column is difficult.

Is there a way to automatically fill a random row in T-SQL without addressing each column by name, so the solution can be applied to different schemas?

I work with SQL Server.

Comment: Does this work?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17189621/insert-into-table-without-specifying-column-names

Comment: Dynamic SQL would be one method. Considering this implies that you have varying definitions, and likely datatypes though, you'll likely need to define logics for each datatype. I.e. a random `varchar` value (`'#asdjkasbjdak'`) isn't going to work when you try to insert that into an `int` or `date(time)` datatype.

Comment: The "by name" part isn't the difficult bit, it's producing random data that's actually appropriate for the column. Given that in order to do that, you need to know the columns and their types, what's the hangup about having to also incorporate their names?

Comment: Also, any dynamic SQL method is very unlikely to be able to incorporate any kind of constraints (like foreign keys, formatting, etc) without a considerably large amount of effort; meaning that it could very likely fail, or be utterly useless.

Comment: do you need completely 10m rows  with unique details or you want to multiply specific amount of rows to 10m?

Comment: As Jeroen Mostert said, the tough part is populating the fields with dummy data but that is also sensible. You may benefit from using RedGate's SQL Data Generator. For example, it can generate valid CC numbers, or you can define your own generators by supplying a pattern/format.