# Importing a csv file into sql server using python

Tags: python, sql-server, csv

I'm currently experiencing a problem importing a csv file to sql using a minor variation of python coding used in a previous answer:-
[Insert csv into sql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25091979/insert-csv-into-sql-database-in-python)

I've run into an issue where I get the following syntax error:-

```
line 28, in insert_records
cursor.execute(insert +'('+ ', '.join(values) +');')
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for 
SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '/'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

I believe I am close to succeeding into getting this csv file to import into sql server. Currently the table in sql server headings already present.  I've attached the python code I am using, the program terminates at [cursor.execute(insert +'('+ ', '.join(values) +');')]

Thanks in advance,
Bryan

```
import pyodbc
import csv
print('connecting')

conn = pyodbc.connect(r'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};'r'SERVER=.\SQLExpress;'r'DATABASE=UFOGBobservations;'r'Trusted_Connection=yes')
print('Connected')
my_cursor = conn.cursor()
print('Cursor established')

def insert_records(table, yourcsv, cursor, cnxn):
    #INSERT SOURCE RECORDS TO DESTINATION
    with open(yourcsv) as csvfile:
        csvFile = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        header = next(csvFile)
        headers = map((lambda x: x.strip()), header)
        insert = 'INSERT INTO {} ('.format(table) + ', '.join(headers) + ') VALUES '
        for row in csvFile:
            values = map((lambda x: "'"+x.strip()+"'"), row)
            cursor.execute(insert +'('+ ', '.join(values) +');')
            conn.commit() #must commit unless your sql database auto-commits

table = 'table_1'
mycsv = r'C:\DataAnalystData\UFOGB_Observations.csv' # SET YOUR FILEPATH
insert_records(table, mycsv, my_cursor, conn)
cursor.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly an escaping issue. It would be safer if you passed the values as a list of parameters to `execute()` rather than manually building a string. This will ensure that they are correctly escaped.

```
insert = 'INSERT INTO {} ('.format(table) + ', '.join(headers) + ') VALUES ({})' \
    .format(', '.join(len(headers) * '?'))  # Add parameter placeholders as ?

for row in csvFile:
    values = map((lambda x: x.strip()), row)  # No need for the quotes
    cursor.execute(insert, values)  # Pass the list of values as 2nd argument
    conn.commit()
```