# Insert CSV data into MSSQL using python, where col headers contain a hyphen

Tags: python, sql-server, csv, insert

Using Code found on [this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50260488/importing-a-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-python) we are able to load data from a CSV to MSSQL where col headers = firstname or first_name. However if the col header contains a hyphen such as first-name then it fails.

Portion of code:

```
with open(yourcsv) as csvfile:
       csvFile = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
       header = next(csvFile)
       headers = map((lambda x: x.strip()), header)
       insert = 'INSERT INTO {} ('.format(table) + ', '.join(headers) + ') VALUES '
       for row in csvFile:
           values = map((lambda x: "'"+x.strip()+"'"), row)
           cursor.execute(insert +'('+ ', '.join(values) +');')
           conn.commit() #must commit unless your sql database auto-commits
```

Error = cursor.execute(insert +'('+ ', '.join(values) +');')
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '-'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")

We need to be able to consume files which can contain a hyphen in the col name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This hard to read snippet of the code can be fixed by using **square brackets** to surround columns names:

```
insert = 'INSERT INTO {} ('.format(table) + '[' + '], ['.join(headers) + ']) VALUES '
```

More details: [What is the use of the square brackets [] in sql statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52898/what-is-the-use-of-the-square-brackets-in-sql-statements)

> The brackets are required if you use keywords or special chars in the
>   column names or identifiers. You could name a column `[First Name]`
>   (with a space)--but then you'd need to use brackets every time you
>   referred to that column.

Comment: - hat tip to you!