# Python import CSV into SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, csv, insert

I am trying to insert a CSV file into SQL Server Express using Python.

I referenced [Importing a csv file into sql server using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50260488/importing-a-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-python) but I still can't get it to work. I have 24 column names in the CSV file, the database table is already created in SQL. The table name is `[dev].[dbo].[Cust]`.

This is the error I am getting now

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Test\Cust.py", line 5, in 
> my_cursor = cnxn.cursor()
> NameError: name 'cnxn' is not defined

Column names are

```
Schedule Date, Schedule In, Schedule Out, Schedule Area, Cust/Non Cust, 
account, Account ID, Last Name, Company Abbr, Company Name, Account Code, 
ADT, Supervisor, position, Available Open Time, Events, 8 - 11 am, 11 - 2 pm, 
2 - 5 pm, 5 - 8 pm, 8 - 11 pm, All Day, Total available, Comment
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
import pyodbc
import csv

# DESTINATION CONNECTION
my_cursor = cnxn.cursor()
my_cnxn = pyodbc.connect('Driver=SQL Server;'
                      'Server=#######\SQLEXPRESS;'
                      'Database=DEV;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
                      
print("Connected")

def insert_records(table, yourcsv, cursor, cnxn):
    #INSERT SOURCE RECORDS TO DESTINATION
    with open(yourcsv) as csvfile:
        csvFile = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        header = next(csvFile)
        headers = map((lambda x: x.strip()), header)
        insert = 'INSERT INTO {} ('.format(table) + ', '.join(headers) + ') VALUES ({})' \
        .format(', '.join(len(headers) * '?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?'))  #                                   Add parameter placeholders as ?

        for row in csvFile:
            values = map((lambda x: x.strip()), row)  # No need for the quotes
            cursor.execute(insert, values)  # Pass the list of values as 2nd argument
            conn.commit()

table = 'Cust'
mycsv = 'C:\test\Cust.csv' # SET YOUR FILEPATH
insert_records(table, mycsv, my_cursor, my_cnxn)
cursor.close()
```

Comment: first use `my_cnxn = pyodbc.connect(...)` and next `my_cursor = my_cnxn.cursor()`. First you have to connect to database to get cursor.  And don't forget to use `my_cnxn` instead of `cnxn`

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I made the changes and now i get a new error any incite?                                                                                                             File "C:\Test\Cust.py", line 33, in <module>
    insert_records(table, mycsv, my_cursor, my_cnxn)
  File "C:\test\Cust.py", line 23, in insert_records
    .format(', '.join(len(headers) * '?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?'))  #Add parameter placeholders as ?
TypeError: object of type 'map' has no len()

Comment: if you have new problem then you should create new question on new page - and you will have new place for code and description. And it will be more readabel. And maybe new persons will see it.

Comment: if you have error then first you could use `print(...)` and `print( type(...) )` to see what you have in variables. Error shows problem with `len(headers)` then first you should check what you have in `headers`. In Python 2 `map` gives `list` but in Python 3 it gives object `map` and sometimes you have to use `list()` to convert it to list. - ie, `len( list(headers) )` or `headers = list(map(...))`

Comment: BTW: object `str` has method `str.strip()` and instead of `map((lambda x: x.strip()), header)` you can do `map(str.strip, header)`