# Connect to SQLite database from Python program

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am receiving line by line streaming data from a device with my Python program. Data looks like this:

```
MSG,4,0,0,80068C,0,2015/01/22,14:40:15.815,2015/01/22,14:40:15.815,,,228.9,212.5,,,-1280,,,,,0
MSG,4,0,0,80068C,0,2015/01/22,14:40:28.722,2015/01/22,14:40:28.722,,,230.5,212.2,,,-1920,,,,,0
MSG,8,0,0,80068C,0,2015/01/22,14:40:34.284,2015/01/22,14:40:34.284,,,,,,,,,,,,0
MSG,8,0,0,80068C,0,2015/01/22,14:40:35.144,2015/01/22,14:40:35.144,,,,,,,,,,,,0
MSG,5,0,0,80068C,0,2015/01/22,14:40:35.144,2015/01/22,14:40:35.144,,5400,,,,,,,,,0,0
MSG,3,0,0,80068C,0,2015/01/22,14:40:36.065,2015/01/22,14:40:36.065,,5375,,,,,,,,,,0
MSG,4,0,0,80068C,0,2015/01/22,14:40:36.644,2015/01/22,14:40:36.644,,,231.6,211.7,,,-1728,,,,,0
MSG,8,0,0,80068C,0,2015/01/22,14:40:37.503,2015/01/22,14:40:37.503,,,,,,,,,,,,0
MSG,4,0,0,80068C,0,2015/01/22,14:40:38.815,2015/01/22,14:40:38.815,,,231.6,211.7,,,-1408,,,,,0
```

Now I want to connect to SQLite database from the program and save each line to the database in CSV format at the instant they are received.

My Python code is given below:

```
from socket import *

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 30003    #our port from before
ADDR = (HOST,PORT)
BUFSIZE = 4096

sock = socket( AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((ADDR))


def readlines(sock, recv_buffer=4096, delim='\n'):
    buffer = ''
    data = True
    while data:
        data = sock.recv(recv_buffer)
        buffer += data

        while buffer.find(delim) != -1:
            line, buffer = buffer.split('\n', 1)
            yield line.strip('\r\n')

    return

for line in readlines(sock):
    print line
```

Comment: isn't sqlite-database and CSV-format somewhat contradicting? To write CSV you don't need a database. On the other hand to access databases from python take a look at SQLAlchemy, they provide a consistent API on the python side, independent from whatever database system you end up using.

Comment: Oh sorry!! my post was little confusing!! Actually my data which I recieve is in CSV format. I have created a table in sqlite with a column for each value. Some field have null value. Now each line is considered as a full set of data and to be written to the table ... Thanks

Comment: If SQLAlchemy is to complex for your need you could also use the build in [sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/sqlite3.html) module. But then you would have to build the SQL statements by hand.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python and SQLite: insert into table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092757/python-and-sqlite-insert-into-table)