# How to insert data into SQLite on page load/refresh using SQLite3?

Tags: python, sqlite, beautifulsoup

I have scraped some weather information onto my website and now want to put them into sqlite3 each time the weather page on my website refreshes. The problem I'm  having is inserting the information into the database as the weather is already displaying on my website.

```
def weather_():
    page = requests.get("https://www.bbc.com/weather/0/2562305")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser') 
    today = soup.find('div',{'data-component-id' : 'forecast'})
    temp = today.find(class_ = 'wr-day-temperature__low')
    low_temp = (temp.get_text())
    return low_temp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Storing Weather Data

Here is useful tutorial on sqlite: http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-python/insert/

and another S.O. link: [Python and SQLite: insert into table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092757/python-and-sqlite-insert-into-table)

and really usefull: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html

---

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('weather.db')
c = conn.cursor()

# Create table
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE weather
             (lowtemp text)''')

# Insert a row of data
c.execute("INSERT INTO weather VALUES (low_temp)")

# Save (commit) the changes
conn.commit()

# We can also close the connection if we are done with it.
# Just be sure any changes have been committed or they will be lost.
conn.close()
```

---

### Use an API

Looked into your scraping and the BBC just uses Meteo ( https://www.meteogroup.com/weather-api ).

This Met Office https://www.metoffice.gov.uk/public/weather  might be really useful for you to get the raw data and skipping the screen scraping.

Data Points: https://www.metoffice.gov.uk/datapoint/about

Here is historical data: https://www.metoffice.gov.uk/pub/data/weather/uk/climate/stationdata/newtonriggdata.txt

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a database file and a table inside to store your weather informations.

Refer [to this doc](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-python/) for the sqlite3 installation.

> CREATE TABLE Weather(Id INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT,low_temperature
>   VARCHAR(25))

Add proper functions to update the database.

```
def create_connection(db_file):
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        return conn
    except Error as e:
        print(e)
    return None

def weather_():
    page = requests.get("https://www.bbc.com/weather/0/2562305")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser') 
    today = soup.find('div',{'data-component-id' : 'forecast'})
    temp = today.find(class_ = 'wr-day-temperature__low')
    low_temp = (temp.get_text())
    return low_temp

//Getting the data
low_temp = weather_()
//Updating the database
your_db_file= '/path_to_your_db_file/your_wheather_db.sqlite'
connector = create_connection(your_db_file)
cursor = connector .cursor()
sql = "INSERT INTO Weather(low_temperature) VALUES ('"+str(low_temp )+"')"
cursor.execute(sql)
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```